# Minimize output interpretation

Tags: mathematical-optimization, output

```
In[166]:= Minimize[{-(((-1 + du) (1 + du)^2)/(
   16 (-1 + du (1 + 2 alpha (-1 + xi))))), 
  1/8 (1 - 4 du + 3 du^2) + alpha (1 - du)/2 du (1 - xi) > 0, 
  0 <= du <= 1, 0 <= alpha <= 1, 0 <= xi <= 1}, {du}]
```

And I get this output (sorry for picture I don't know how to copy mathematica's output)

[image]

I don't see the optimal du here, but only the value of the objective function. What does it mean? Where can I find more resources on working with this function and Maximize?

Comment: Did you try `Minimize[{-(((-1 + du) (1 + du)^2)/(16 (-1 + 
          du (1 + 2 alpha (-1 + xi))))), 
   1/8 (1 - 4 du + 3 du^2) + alpha (1 - du)/2 du (1 - xi) > 0, 
   0 <= du <= 1, 0 <= alpha <= 1, 0 <= xi <= 1}, {du}] // InputForm`?

Comment: Now I see it, in input form but I've got the Piecewise solutions... why is that? Thanks

Comment: Look at a simpler example "A minimization problem containing parameters: " in the "Basic Examples" section of the documentation to `Minimize`.

Comment: The value for `du` is there, it just did not fit onto one screen. You can do it in steps if you want: First define `opt=Minimize[...];` then `opt[[1]]` will show the value of the objective function and `opt[[2]]` will show the value of `du`.

Comment: `Minimize[{-(((-1 + du) (1 + du)^2)/(16 (-1 + 
         du (1 + 2 alpha (-1 + xi))))), 
  1/8 (1 - 4 du + 3 du^2) + alpha (1 - du)/2 du (1 - xi) >= 0, 
  0 <= du <= 1, 0 <= alpha <= 1, 0 <= xi <= 1}, {du, alpha, xi}]`

Comment: @cvgmt Minimizing with respect to `du`, with `alpha` and `xi` as parameters (which is what OP seems to want to do), is not the same thing as minimizing with respect to `du` and `alpha` and `xi`.

Comment: @user293787  Never seen such an optimization problem. So I think the questioner asked the wrong question.

Comment: @cvgmt The documentation for Minimize contains an example, namely `Minimize[a x^2 + b x + c, x]`, as pointed out by @user64494. Whether OP actually wanted to solve a problem other than they say here is not something I am in a position to tell.

Comment: @user293787  What I means is that  I never seen  a parametric optimization problems. add  conditions such as `0 <= du <= 1, 0 <= alpha <= 1, 0 <= xi <= 1` .

Comment: @cvgmt I do not know. Maybe this can be used to convey assumptions about the parameters to `Minimize`? But maybe you are right and OP is confusing the two problems.

Comment: Thank you for the details. Alpha and xi are indeed the parameters and the variable is du, so the basic formulation is the one in the post. Given these have a real world interpretation but are not under the influence of the optimizer, he cannot optimize over them. I've also checked the manual and examples before posting, but I was confused by the fact that the example worked and with my problem the optimal value wasn't appearing.

Comment: @KArrow'sBest Hi, I was just going to post an answer to your other question but you deleted it. Anyhow, as you may have figured out yourself, the origin of your confusion is that the maxima are exactly on the boundary of the domain defined by your inequalities. If instead of `0.44` you use exact numbers `44/100` then `Maximize` will return an exact result and you can check that it is on the boundary exactly. Hope this helps.

Comment: @user293787 sorry about this. I guessed the reason would be that one (however, I had to change to NMaximize to get the values and rewrite the function as also functions of alpha and xi). This is interesting though: the two functions I was comparing are basically two components of a piecewise discontinuous funct, that in general in economics we optimize separately and then compare. This would mean that the second function eval. at optim is never larger than the first one, given that it's solution is at the boundary with the first. (and that I've lost two days xD).THX for confirming it

Comment: @KArrow'sBest Interesting. To be clear, I only tried `alpha` and `xi` equal to `0.44`, in that case it was on the boundary if we trust `Maximize`. For other values of the parameter it may not be on the boundary.

Comment: Yes I was using this `Do[
 Print[  m1 = 
    NMaximize[{cw[dcw, pcw, alpha], 
      0 <= dcw <= 1, (
       2 (2 pcw + alpha (-1 + dcw) dcw (-1 + xi)))/(-1 + dcw)^2 <= 
       0}, {pcw, dcw}, WorkingPrecision -> 6], {alpha, xi}]
  Print[m2 = 
    NMaximize[{uw[d, p , alpha, xi], (
       p + alpha (1 - d)/2 d (1 - xi))/((1 - d)^2/4 + 
        alpha (1 - d)/2 d (1 - xi)) > 0, 0 <= d <= 1}, {p, d}, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 6], { alpha, xi}], {alpha, 0, 1, 1/10}, {xi, 
  0, 1, 1/10}]` when shouldn't we trust it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

You will get simpler results if you simplify the results using the constraints as assumptions in the simplification. Looking only at the [`MinValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinValue.html)

```
min = Assuming[
  {1/8 (1 - 4 du + 3 du^2) + alpha (1 - du)/2 du (1 - xi) > 0,
   0 <= du <= 1, 0 <= alpha <= 1, 0 <= xi <= 1},
  MinValue[{
     -(((-1 + du) (1 + du)^2)/(16 (-1 + du (1 + 2 alpha (-1 + xi))))), 
     1/8 (1 - 4 du + 3 du^2) + alpha (1 - du)/2 du (1 - xi) > 0, 
     0 <= du <= 1, 0 <= alpha <= 1, 0 <= xi <= 1}, du] // 
  FullSimplify]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, for the option. But I only observe the objective function and not the optimal choice with this right?

Comment: Use `Minimize` and you will get both the `MinValue` and `ArgMin`, I opted to only show the `MinValue` for this example. In any event, you want to use the constraints to simplify.

Comment: I love the assuming associated to minvalue, however when I use it with argmin I am not able to get the results because it seems to run forever

Comment: You can trade potential performance for speed. For `ArgMin` use `Simplify` rather than `FullSimplify`. The simplification will be limited (`LeafCount` only drops to 1239 from 1271), but completes quickly. The `Root` expressions don't simplify.